# Select the right data in PHP

Tags: php

I have an interface below

[image]

When I click the edit button (icon pencil), the form bellow will appear

[image]

The edit button has a code below in php file :

```
$elisting ="";

    $queryf = "select employee.id as myid,jobtitle,info,locid,deptid,gender,dob,emid,employee$cid.name,username,dept,datejoin,location.name as loc from  employee

        left join location on location$cid.id = employee.locid 

        inner join department on department.id = employee.deptid order by username

    ";

    $resultf = pg_query($queryf); 

    $numrows = pg_numrows($resultf);

    while ($rowf = pg_fetch_array($resultf)) {

        $ct=$ct+1;

        $myid = $rowf[myid];

        $uname = $rowf[username];

        $loc1 = $rowf[loc];

        $dept = $rowf[dept];

        $date = $rowf[datejoin];

        $name = $rowf[name];

        $emid = $rowf[emid];

        $dob = $rowf[dob];

        $gender = $rowf[gender];

        $job = $rowf[jobtitle];

        $info = $rowf[info];

        $datejoin = $rowf[datejoin];

        $locid = $rowf[locid];

        $deptid = $rowf[deptid];

        $newbal = $rowf[newbal];

        $templatelist = "";

        $tempcn = 0;

        $querytemp = "select tid,ltype from leaveatemplate$cid where username='$uname' order by tid desc";

        $resulttemp = pg_query($querytemp); 

        while ($rowtemp = pg_fetch_array($resulttemp)) {

            $tempcn = $tempcn +1;

            $tid = $rowtemp[tid];

            $ltype = $rowtemp[ltype];

            if($tempcn=="1")

                $templatelist = "$ltype|$tid";

            else

                $templatelist = $templatelist.","."$ltype|$tid";

        }

        $elisting=$elisting."<tr><td align=\"center\">$uname</td><td align=\"center\">$loc1</td><td align=\"center\">$dept</td><td align=\"center\">$date</td><td align=\"center\"><button class=\"btn btn-mini\"data-toggle=\"modal\"href=\"#long\"
onClick=\"javascript:edit('$name','$uname','$emid','$dob','$gender','$job','$info','$datejoin','$locid','$deptid','$myid','$templatelist', '$value');\"><i class=\"icon-pencil\"></i></a><button class=\"btn btn-mini\" data-toggle=\"modal\" href=\"#static\" rel=\"tooltip\"  data-original-title=\"Delete\" onClick=\"javascript:delrec('$myid');\"><i class=\"icon-remove\"></i></a></td>
        </tr>\n";
        }
```

I wonder how can the code select the right data as the button clicked? Because I saw there is no requirement in the query, for example where `id = 123` or something like that. When choose adam, the adam's data will appear. Anyone can explain this?

UPDATE:

```
function edit(a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,l){
        document.getElementById("frm").id.value=k;
      document.getElementById("frm").name.value=a;
      document.getElementById("frm").username.value=b;
      document.getElementById("frm").emid.value=c;
      document.getElementById("frm").dob.value=d;
      setCheckedValue(document.forms['frm'].elements['gender'],e);
      document.getElementById("frm").job.value=f;
      document.getElementById("frm").info.value=g;
      document.getElementById("frm").datejoin.value=h;
      document.getElementById('locid').value=i;
      document.getElementById('deptid').value=j;
}
```

Comment: sounds like an ajax request is made and populate the form. You can verify that with Chrome console (F12) or with Firebug plugin in Firefox.

Comment: how to verify with Firebug?

Comment: same. Press F12 to run Firebug (check console tab)

Comment: should I click the  edit button first?

Comment: open whatever console you have, then yes, click on Edit and see what your consoles will log

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line explain everything:

```
onClick=\"javascript:edit('$name','$uname','$emid','$dob','$gender','$job','$info','$datejoin','$locid','$deptid','$myid','$templatelist', '$value');
```

As you can see in the javascript edit function the id of the object (`$myid` i guess) is passed along with all the other properties of the object.

Comment: how can javascript do that? I've tried to deleted the `edit()` but the data still in the form. I usually use query select ... where ... so it will give appropriate data..

Comment: well from your code is not clear the full situation, could you please post the content of the `edit` function?

Comment: As you can see the edit function does nothing more than setting data of an already existing form that will be then submitted. Probably when you deleted the edit function and reloaded the page you had a cache issue so in reality nothing really changed and the edit function was still in place

Comment: I think so, but how can the select give the right data without requirement (where id 123 or something like that) in the query?

Comment: Because the select is not fetching for a particilar row but for all the rows that should be displayed, iterating throught them to display row by row. The id and other data is fetched for EACH row not for a particular one

Comment: Thank you, Sir. I understand now. So, can I use $uname outside the while to run some query?

Comment: Not outside but inside. If you use it after the while you would use the last name fetched, before and you wouldn't have a value at all. What you can do is saving all the $uname values in an array for later use

Comment: Can I use $uname as the button is clicked? If the button for adam is clicked, so the $uname will be adam.